# send contact form via email in CodeIgniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, email

I've seen a number of examples, closest I've got is trying to use smtp but I can't even get that working, not done this for ages just had to revisit an old project and it was never working in the first place.

This is my form in View:

```
<!--contact form-->
<div id="booking-form">
  <div class="form-div">
    <form class="form" id="form1" action="site/postData">
      <p>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]]         feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
      </p>

      <p class="email">
        <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
      </p>

      <p class="text">
         <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      </p>

      <p class="datepick">
         <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="validate[required] feedback-input" placeholder="Date">
      </p>
      <div class="submit">
           <input type="submit" value="BOOK" class="button-blue"/>
           <!--<div class="ease"></div>-->
      </div>
    </form>
  </div><!--EOF form-div-->
  </div> <!--EOF contact form-->
```

This is everything I have in the controller, PostData is the function I have been working on:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $data['myValue'] = "Home";

        $this->load->view('index', $data);
    }

function postData () {

        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->from($this->input->post('name'), 'Your Name');
        $this->email->to('torilclack@gmail.com'); 

        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
        $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

        $this->email->send();

        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
      }
   }
```

The error I am currently getting:

```
Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
From: "Your Name" <>
Return-Path: <>
Reply-To: "" <>
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5451ebd5b2b53>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?utf-8?Q?Email_Test?=
Testing the email class.
```

I've seen the error in other posts and did try SMTP as mentioned above, but was just getting a broken PHP issue from that so was no better off. I know I had this working ages ago and broke it again back then. Don't think it can be too far off?

Help would be appreciated. Will keep looking in the meantime

Comment: domain name in `from` should match `server domain name`. its a user input in your case. **OR** you have some mistake in email config.

Comment: Is this on a testing server or a live server?

Comment: It's server from the course I used to be on, and didn't pass thanks to this specific problem, live but not able to be looked at outside of New Zealand. Still works so been using for testing since I'm only really finishing off this 1 site.

Comment: Have not touched the code this is referring to: $this->load->library('email');